# Hadoop: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException

Tags: java, json, hadoop

Same question was asked three years back. But the answer is not solving my problem,it seems. According to the answer, I have added "json-simple-1.1.1" in ubuntu, in the lib "/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/lib". But my hadoop MR job is failing. I am using hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u5. What I am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated much.
my mapper method in java.

[image]
The failed output.
[image]
The lib.
[image]

my input .text is one liner.
{"name":"aaa", "title:"bbb"} .I tried with .json also did not work!

I export the jar file from eclipse to ubuntu hadoop and run "hadoop jar JSONReadFromFileCheck.jar JSONReadFromFileCheck /inputpath /outputpath".

I also put the json-simple-1.1.1.jar in hadoop as follows. Please see.

[image]

jfyi, I ran a sample code in java as follows, it ran without a problem.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class jsoncheck {public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String s = "{\"name\":\"aaa\",\"title\":\"bbb\"}";
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(s);
        String vout = (String) json.get("title");System.out.println(vout);}}
```

I see that String does not accept double quote inside String, and jsonparser will not allow to remove double quote :-). I wonder when mapper gets input as text, in what format it receives!

Comment: there is an exception before the exception you, could you post a snapshot of it ? by the way your problem is interesting , it wanted to throw an exception(`ParseException`) but didn't find the class so it threw `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: in short: even if you resolved `ClassNotFoundException` I think a `ParseException` would be thrown which means `s` could be not a valid json

Comment: How do you submit your application? I would not place any dependency into Java lib folder, rather Hadoop classpath..

Comment: hi guys, I updated my comments as per your comments. Please see and advise.